# Materials & Lighting : How to get "Shadow puppetry" effect

Tags: materials, light, photorealism

I am trying to make a scenic view where I want to show people behind an umbrella. The effect I am trying to achieve is getting the shadow of the people onto the translucent umbrella. The reference image is attached below.

[image]

What I can understand is the umbrella can be given a mix of translucent and transparent material and put the Area light object in front of the person, and decrease the size and spread to low value. What I am achieving is not satisfying.
[image]

So, I am unable to understand what needs to be changed to get that effect and any other ways to achieve the effect properly. Any help to get this kind of appearance?? .. It would be great if someone can help me with the science of lighting in this case as well... (Also how to avoid multiple shadows from multiple light sources)

Comment: Yes @moonboots . 1. I need it to be more darker and crisp shadow. 2. I want to avoid multiple shadows. 3. I want to see if there are any other/better ways to get the results by changing the light settings or material.

Comment: @moonboots . where can i find the shadow settings in Cycles?

Answer (score 5):

*Translucent* seems to be the good node for this purpose, if you want to make it slightly transparent mix it with a *Transparent* node.

In Cycles, in the *Properties > Object Data* panel, you can lower down the sun *Angle* value if you want a crisp shadow. You can also deactivate the *Cast Shadow* option:

[image]